# Why doesn't my DLL execute the EntryPoint?

Tags: c++, winapi, lua, dll-injection

I added the lua package to my c++ project, but anytime lua is included in my project no functions are called when my DLL gets attached, but when I dont include lua the messagebox appears on attachment. I'm certain it isn't the injection program since I tested my DLL w/ multiple programs and it's now driving me crazy. Does anyone have any solutions or steps in the right path? I would really appreciate it!

Package Used: https://bitbucket.org/sgrottel_nuget/lua/overview

EDIT: Including lua headers will remove functionality from my dll. Removing the lua headers (commenting out "#include "lua.hpp") will let the messagebox pop up. Am I using the lua package wrong or is there a small step I missed?

```
#include "FVM.h" // includes lua headers etc. (when removed function works on attachment)


    // Entry point
    BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
        DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
        LPVOID lpReserved
    )
    {
        switch (ul_reason_for_call)
        {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "attached", "Function", MB_OK);
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "attached", "Function", MB_OK);
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot call `MessageBox` in `DllMain`. No user32 functions are allowed. Instead, use `OutputDebugString` and the DebugView utility to see the output.

Comment: Hi unplug, can you show a sample that can reproduce this issue? I add` #include "lua.h"` in dllmain.cpp but the messagebox appears.

Comment: Use `OutputDebugString` for trace messages and `DebugView` as viewer.

Comment: Hi Rita, I simply include the "lua.hpp" file in the "FVM.h" header file. The lua.hpp file includes all the required headers for lua to be loaded. Once the header for lua is removed the messagebox pops up once the DLL is attached. Basically if I just comment "#include "FVM.h" then the DLL functions as it should but I need the lua c api for my program to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this issue. Please follow my steps to see if it can reproduce this issue.

1. Create a main application using Windows Desktop Application template.
2. Create a DLL application using Dynamic-Link Library(DLL) template.
3. Install LUA nuget package to the DLL application.
4. Add the header file to the dllmain.cpp and add MessageBoxA same with your code.
5. Load DLL in the main application:

   `HMODULE myDll = LoadLibraryA("D:\\TestDllLoad\\Debug\\Dll1.dll");`

The result is the message box display "attached" every time I launch the main application.

[image]